# How to import files/modules from other directory in python?

Tags: python, import, module

I want to import some files/modules from other directory.
I have placed an **init**.py in the directory but still not able to import the files/modules.
I am using Pycharm 2019.

I want to use **init**.py only method and not the sys.path.append.

thanks in Advance!

Comment: I just realized from your other comments that you have `init.py` files instead of `__init__.py` files, which is probably why you can't import anything from these folders (assuming I understood you correctly). Change the filenames to `__init__.py` and try it

Comment: thanks ofer Sadan, but I am typing ____init____.py and it autocorrecting to init.py in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple ways to do that, I'll name two -

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'path/to/your/py_file')

import py_file
```

is relatively easy, and another one is if you're using pycharm just **mark** the directory of which you want to import from as a **sources root**.

Comment: actually I am also using the pycharm's default python package making system. but it is still giving me nothing as I am unable to import the module to the current directory. so please give me solution as I am new to the programming.

Comment: thanks Yoel Nisanov but as I said i dont want to use the sys.path method but __init__.py

Comment: all my projects are in PycharmProject dir, and all the projects are including the __init__.py file. but still I am not able to import any file to the different dir, but I am able to import in the same dir.

Comment: @OferSadan Hi mate, as you probably saw I gave him 2 options BECAUSE he said he doesn't want to use sys.path.append. And since he said he is using pycharm I think the solution I provided should be enough.

Comment: listen @MartynMystery, mark the directory you want to import from as sources root this should solve your issue... If it still doesn't work please notify me...

Comment: @YoelNisanov I'm retracting my comment beacause perhaps you're right and I judged too quickly

Comment: @OferSadan it's 100% fine (: